# Ganglia only displays localhost

Tags: ubuntu, ganglia

I have a fresh install of Ganglia and it only shows the localhost. It seems no matter what I change nothing works. I'm sure I'm missing something stupid any help out there.

```
/* This configuration is as close to 2.5.x default behavior as possible
The values closely match ./gmond/metric.h definitions in 2.5.x */
globals {
daemonize = yes
setuid = yes
user = ganglia
debug_level = 0
max_udp_msg_len = 1472
mute = no
deaf = no
host_dmax = 0 /*secs */
cleanup_threshold = 300 /*secs */
gexec = no
send_metadata_interval = 15
}

/* If a cluster attribute is specified, then all gmond hosts are wrapped 
inside
* of a <CLUSTER> tag.  If you do not specify a cluster tag, then all 
<HOSTS> will
* NOT be wrapped inside of a <CLUSTER> tag. */
cluster {
name = "Production"
owner = "unspecified"
latlong = "unspecified"
url = "unspecified"
}

 /* The host section describes attributes of the host, like the location */
host {
location = "unspecified"
}

/* Feel free to specify as many udp_send_channels as you like.  Gmond
used to only support having a single channel */
udp_send_channel {
# mcast_join = 239.2.11.71
Host = 10.9.23.251
#   Host = 10.6.18.55
port = 8649
ttl = 1
}
udp_send_channel {
# mcast_join = 239.2.11.71
#  Host = 10.9.23.251
Host = 10.9.23.14
port = 8649
#  ttl = 1
}


 /* You can specify as many udp_recv_channels as you like as well. */
udp_recv_channel { # mcast_join = 239.2.11.71

 port = 8649
 #bind = 239.2.11.71
 }
```

Comment: This is only a excerpt of `/etc/ganglia/gmond`? Or did you delete the rest of the configuration? You send the data to two servers: 10.9.23.14 and 10.9.23.251? This configuration is also running on the other hosts? Any firewalls in between that could block the communication? Try to start on the command line with `gmond -d 10` on both the receiving and sender side. Check

Comment: My collection server is 10.9.23.251 the client is a Windows device at 10.9.23.14. no firewall and its on the same subnet. Am I adding the client in the wrong place?

Comment: You have to run the client on the Windows computer as well. Ganglia does send the collected information to the computer that is specified in the `udp_send_channel` section. It does not grab the information like Nagios e.g. does. So you have to run a client on the Windows computer as well.

Comment: I have sflow installed on the windows client. Is there something on the Windows side that I need to set other than the basic install?

Comment: During the install it asks for ddns or you can uncheck the box. I unchecked the box and put in the IP and port for my collection server. Was that part wrong? What are others doing to get this working?